# How to round off 'percentage' to two decimal places in following query?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *, 
       MATCH (question_text) AGAINST 
             ('A nucleotide consists of' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS percentage 
FROM OCN.match_questions 
WHERE MATCH (question_text) AGAINST 
            ('A nucleotide consists of' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

I want to rounf off the percentage to two decimal places after integer or only integer part should get fetched. Both the queries I needed but I'm not able to write it in correct way. I tried the following query but it didn't work out.

```
SELECT *, 
       MATCH (question_text) AGAINST 
             ('A nucleotide consists of' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
             AS ROUND(percentage,2) 
FROM OCN.match_questions 
WHERE MATCH (question_text) AGAINST 
      ('A nucleotide consists of' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: So, ROUND() perhaps !?!?

Comment: `ROUND(MATCH(...) AGAINST ('...' ...),2) as something`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROUND( 
          -- a first parameter of ROUND goes here:
          MATCH (question_text) AGAINST 
                    ('A nucleotide consists of' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) 
          -- and a second parameter of ROUND goes after the comma:
             , 2 ) AS percentage
FROM ........
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

> **ROUND(X,D)** 
>   Rounds the argument X to D decimal places.
>   X is the first parameter, and D is the second parameter